# Is iPhone 5 screen shots are mandatory for new version app submission?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, app-store

I am uploading new  binary for my already uploaded app on appstore it shows following errors

**You must provide all required contact information. To edit your contact details, click Edit in the App Review section.**

**You must upload a large app icon that is 1024 x 1024 pixels. To upload the icon, click Edit in the Version Information section below.**

However in my MetaData section there is option for iPhone 5 iPod touch (5 th generation)  screen shots . But doesn't show any error in this section .

So i am confused do i need to upload the screen shots for iPhone 5 or not 
Will my app gets rejected ?

Thanks in advance

Paggy123

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following was sent to developers in an e-mail after the iPhone announcement in September:

> If you are updating your app for iPhone 5 and iPod touch (5th
>   generation), you must provide additional screenshots to support the
>   new screen dimensions for the App Store.

If your app is not optimized for this screen size then obviously you don't need to supply screenshots at that size.

If your app *does* support the 4-inch (iPhone 5 & 5th generation iPod touch) screen size, then yes, you **must** provide screenshots for the new screen size. It's likely that 4-inch screen support isn't detected in your app until they review it, which means that iTunes Connect will never show you an error about this - they just won't approve your app if you haven't supplied the correct screenshots.

Regarding the other errors, iTunes Connect was recently updated to accept contact information for those uploading apps (in case of review problems) - this is required for new apps and any edits to existing apps. Additionally, some time ago they began requiring 1024x1024 images for the "Large App Icon" commonly known as iTunesArtwork, so you'll need to provide this as well.

Comment: hello @ev0lution do i need to run my app on iPhone 5 or iPod touch 5th generation . Please tell me.

Comment: Both devices have the same 4-inch screen. You don't *have* to run your app on either device, there is a "Retina (4-inch)" option in the simulator.

Comment: thnx for your quick reply ,but still there are some questions . I am having xcode 4.2 and my question is that to upload new version on app store do i need to make any changes in settings with xcode 4.2 in reference with warning from apple" updating your app for iPhone 5 and iPod touch (5th generation) you must provide additional screenshots to support the new screen dimensions for the App Store" . Hope you understand what i mean to say.Thnx again

Comment: The only thing that indicates whether or not your app supports the 4-inch screen is whether you have a "Default-568h@2x.png" file or not. If you haven't added that, your app won't natively support the 4-inch screen (which is fine!) and you don't need to change any other settings or provide other screenshots.

Comment: ok that means if i submit my binary without screen shots , my binary will not get  rejected .

Comment: That's correct. If your app doesn't support the new screen size, you don't have to (and obviously can't) supply screenshots for the new size.

Comment: I would add though that it benefits you to support the iPhone 5, and I would imagine at some point Apple will require this support anyway. So you might as well get the pain over with.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the OP's question, which is about the confusing interface that shows an error but offers no way to fix the problem, i.e., no way to upload the 1024x1024 icon it's requiring.

Comment: @CodeRoadie The question is "Are iPhone 5 screen shots are mandatory for new version app submission?" - and the OP repeats this at the end of his submission. This is what I answered. The OP was more concerned about this problem than the error you pointed out, and therefore was satisfied. If the question was related to the 1024 app icon error, my answer would not be sufficient.

Comment: @ev0lution Hmm, I see your point. If you "edit" your answer, I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: @CodeRoadie I was just about to edit it, but I don't think the problem you mentioned actually exists. The error states what you need to do to fix the problem (i.e. "click Edit in the Version Information section below"), and this is correct - in the "Version Information" popup, there is a "Large App Icon" thumbnail with a "Choose File" button if your app is in an editable state. Apologies if I misunderstood, or this isn't what you were referring to.

Answer (score 2):

FROM APPLE:  (https://developer.apple.com/news/)

Make Your Apps Look Great on the Retina Display and iPhone 5

March 21, 2013

Starting May 1, new apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built for iOS devices with Retina display and iPhone apps must also support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5.

So, it looks like we are all going to have to support the 4 inch display.  It was inevitable.